# SQL: Compare entries in a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Candidates`, with `CandidateNameID`, `YearOfElection` and `Votes` received in the year. I want to get all candidates whose vote count are increasing year after year.

Sample Entries:

```
CandidateId  year                    votes
------------ ----------------------- ----------
p1           2008-01-01 00:00:00     120       
p2           2008-01-01 00:00:00     15        
p3           2008-01-01 00:00:00     18        
p1           2009-01-01 00:00:00     115       
p2           2009-01-01 00:00:00     20        
p3           2009-01-01 00:00:00     20        
p1           2010-01-01 00:00:00     125       
p2           2010-01-01 00:00:00     19        
p3           2010-01-01 00:00:00     21
```

Sample output:

```
CandidateID
--------------
p3
```

What I have tried yet:

I tried grouping by `candidateID` and then sort by year. I can't figure out how to compare the entries for a candidate. Does it have anything to do with having? I am new to querying databases.

Comment: what about writing a procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Candidates
    ([CandidateId] varchar(12), [year] DATETIME, [votes] INT)
;

INSERT INTO #Candidates
    ([CandidateId], [year], [votes])
VALUES
    ('p1', '2008-01-01 00:00:00', '120'),
    ('p2', '2008-01-01 00:00:00', '15'),
    ('p3', '2008-01-01 00:00:00', '18'),
    ('p1', '2009-01-01 00:00:00', '115'),
    ('p2', '2009-01-01 00:00:00', '20'),
    ('p3', '2009-01-01 00:00:00', '20'),
    ('p1', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '125'),
    ('p2', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '19'),
    ('p3', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '21')
;

SELECT [CandidateId] FROM #Candidates
WHERE [CandidateId] NOT IN 
(
    SELECT T1.[CandidateId] FROM #Candidates T1
    INNER JOIN #Candidates T2 ON T2.[CandidateId] = T1.[CandidateId] 
    AND T1.[YEAR] > T2.[YEAR] AND T1.votes < T2.votes
)
GROUP BY [CandidateId]

DROP TABLE #Candidates
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `not exists` :

```
   select candidateId from candidates c
   where not exists 
   (
    select 1 
    from candidates 
    where candidateId = c.candidateId and year < c.year and votes > c.votes
   ) 
   group by candidateId 
   having count(*) = 
   (select count(*) from candidates where candidateId = c.candidateId)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be5b7/21)

Comment: It returns p1 as well. I guess it is checking only for the last year.

Comment: `(year < c.year and DATEDIFF(year, [year], c.year) = 1`? And possibli without last `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I think you can't be sure that years are sequential. Otherwise it would be much simpler.